# Why would a PC be on a different subnet?

Tags: networking, home-networking, dhcp

There are several devices connected to my home network, some wired, some wireless. With the exception of one PC, they all have the same subnet mask (`255.255.255.0`), default gateway (`192.168.1.254`) and IPs suggesting they're all on the same network (`192.168.1.*`).

However, there's one Windows PC with a wired connection to the router whose network connection is very different and is preventing it from connecting to the other machines connected to the same router or even reaching the router's configuration web application. Its IP address is `207.???.???.???`, subnet mask is `255.255.252.0` and default gateway `207.???.???.???`. Even the DHCP server listed in the network connection details is different from what the other machines have.

I've looked around the router's configuration and haven't seen anything DHCP-related that would assign this machine a different subnet or IP address. Could this be a configuration issue on the machine's ethernet adapter? None of the other machines on the network with a wired connection have this problem.

edit: more details

- The router is an Actiontec T3200M.
- IPv4 on the PC is set to "Obtain IP address automatically" and "Obtain DNS server address automatically"
- There are no entries in the list of DMZ Hosted Devices or IPv6 DMZ Hosted Devices. What's strange is that the LAN status on the router says there's an active ethernet connection on port 1 which is where the machine is connected to but the machine is not displayed in the list of connected machines.

[LAN Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6Wpo.png)

Comment: Try uninstalling/reinstalling the adapter in device manager. Flush the dns caches etc if you haven't already done so. I'm assuming this happens on any port you connect to with this PC? It's not unheard of to get a dead port... But that wouldn't really explain the weird DHCP that you are receiving. What's also interesting is that port one in your image has passed more traffic than the port you said was working ok. Is this FiOS? Your moca port also seems to be down in the image.

Comment: Still no luck after reinstalling the network adapter drivers and flushing DNS cache. You are right, it doesn't matter which port on the router I connect to, it's on that different subnet every time.

If by dead port you mean there's no traffic on the port, there is actually an internet connection.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart The port that's working is for a machine I just connected to the network to test if the problem applies to all wired connections. Looks like the problem is specific to one PC.

Moca port is indeed down, not using it. My provider is Telus Fibre.

Comment: You might want to try booting a live Ubuntu USB  to rule out software/malware etc. If you boot into Linux and it's working as expected, you know something is up with the windows installation.

Comment: Sounds like that PC is getting it's settings from your ISP which makes me think you have the wiring wrong.  Perhaps plugging the cable from your modem into a LAN port instead of the WAN port for example.

Answer (score 0):

> However, there's one Windows PC with a wired connection to the router
>   ...

Your wireless router has a different subnet than the wired router, OR, the wireless section of the one router is a different subnet that the wired section. This happens with Sonic Wall and perhaps others (but most combined routers keep everything on one subnet). Check on your router if wired is isolated from wireless

If two routers, hook up LAN to LAN, give one router a static IP address on your network and turn DHCP OFF on this router.

If you have a Sonic Wall, look up the Sonic Wall documentation for router wireless onto the same subnet as wired.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot reach the router from this PC, I don't think the router is misconfigured. It sounds like the PC has a static IP address. Remove any hardcoded IP address information on the PC, and let it find a DHCP address from the router.